# How can i find if the user input was the same as an array's value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have tried many thing's but still no success.

```
let rolearr = ["member", "nsfw", "minecraft", "lol", "dota", "gta", "rule"]
if(rolearr.indexOf(args[0] > -1 )){
   //somthing
}
```

args is the user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, the `indexOf` function param should be `args[0]` that i'm supposing is a `string`, in your code you are passing a `boolean` as a result of evaluate `args[0] > -1`

```
let rolearr = ["member", "nsfw", "minecraft", "lol", "dota", "gta", "rule"]
if(rolearr.indexOf(args[0]) > -1 ){
   //something
}
```

[here is a live example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pQWNYq)

Comment: You are welcome, consider mark it as an answer if it was helpful! :)